# Horário de Verão incorreto no PostgreSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, servidor

Com a mudança de data do início do horário de verão neste ano, banco de dados postgreSQL estão com problemas (assim como vários outros sistemas), passando a informar o `timezone` com `dls` (daylight saving) a partir do dia 21/10.

**Como proceder para que o SGDB informe o horário corretamente ?**

> Utilizo a versão 9.1, em versões atualizadas o problema não ocorre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois os arquivos de Timezone do banco estão desatualizados:

1. Acesse o [site do postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/download/), e baixe a versão mais recente disponível (apenas os binários, não precisa do instalador);
2. Pare o serviço
3. Copie o arquivo do timezone desejado (no meu caso, São Paulo):

   `pgsql\share\timezone\America\Sao_Paulo`

   para o diretório equivalente na instalação do banco.
4. Inicie o serviço novamente.

---

Vale lembrar que o timezone deve estar definido no postgres.conf como:

```
timezone='America/Sao_Paulo'
```

e, o banco de dados também:

```
alter database databasename set timezone to 'America/Sao_Paulo';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Observe se trabalha com sistemas de mais de um fuso horário, eu recomendo configurar em UTC.
2. Note que você pode definir o fuso horário em ‘timezone=”America/Sao_Paulo” em postgresql.conf
3. Copie o/os arquivos de “timezone” atualizados de uma versão mais recente e substitua-os e reinicie o serviço.
4. O Postgresql quando definido o fuso horário local “localtime”, em alguns sistemas operacionais seguirá o fuso horário definido no nível do sistema operacional o qual quando atualizado traz atualizações de horário de verão, use o comando “show timezone” no Postgres para verificar o fuso horário.

Answer (score 0):

Para sair do horário de verão, **GMT+3**
Para entrar **GMT+2**

Segue comandos abaixo:

```
alter system set timezone="GMT+3";
select pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: O problema dessa abordagem é que, toda vez que começar ou terminar o horário de verão, vai ter que ser mudado novamente. A resposta do Rovann acima é melhor, porque timezones como `America/Sao_Paulo` já sabem se tem que usar -2, -3 ou qualquer outro valor, e já fazem a mudança automaticamente. Além disso, no horário de verão brasileiro, o correto é -3 e -2, e não +3 e +2: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo